# Streaming a video in angular

Tags: angular, express, video-streaming

Right now I'm creating a personal project for a web video gallery. I've set up node express as backend server where I upload the videos and afterwards my angular app displays them in a list. I need a video player, which to stream the uploaded videos from the server. To be accurate, **how do I get the video from the server to the angular app video player**? I tried to pass direct address from server into source, *but nothing happens*.

Answer (score 1):

In the future please provide some code to let other see what you tried.

I think that the best solution would be that when you upload your file with express, you should also create a entry in a database where you would stock filename and filepath.

You also need to configure express so that it [staticly serve](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) your video files.

Then in angular you make an [http request](https://angular.io/guide/http) to your express app to get the list of video file (so you're requesting the data you stored in your database).

And finally you can display them with the [html video tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)